# React render quantity of components based on a numeric value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to pass in a value to a component and render multiple child components based on that value. e.g. if I pass in `count={4}` in props, then I want to render 4 `<Icon/>` components. If I pass in 5, I want to render 5, and so on.

At the moment, all I can think to do is to take the value and turn it into an array (i.e. do a `for` loop and push a placeholder element to an array with each iteration) and then do a map on that array. But that seems like overkill.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
...
return(
 Array.from({length: props.count}, () => <Icon />)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking a way to `map` amount of children to be populated. Check this live example: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/mapping-child-components

This is the core code from that example:

```
const Icon = ({index}) => (
  <View><Text>{`Icon #${index + 1}`}</Text></View>
);

const Icons = ({count}) => (
  Array.from({length: count}).map((_item, index) => <Icon index={index}/>)
)

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Icons count={5} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop for this

```
    for(let i = 0; i < count ; i++){
        return <Icon />
    }
```

If this doesn't work, you can do the following. It's a bit modern es6 function. Try this..

```
   {[...Array(count)].map((x, i) =>
      <Icon key={i} />
   )}
```

Comment: I did this, and then ran into other another problem: How do I render that group? I can't store the result of a for loop directly in a variable, and I can't render a for loop directly in JSX. Would you mind adding the full syntax here?